# localhost:81 is redirecting me to localhost:80 for one particular folder

Tags: localhost, wamp, wampserver

I'm running WAMP and originally had it run on the default port 80.

I just switched it over to run on port 81 instead now, which for the most part works fine.

However, every time I try to go to

```
localhost:81/dev/
```

in Chrome, I get sent to

```
localhost/dev/
```

and get a 404 error.

This is not the case for any other of my folders/files, and even for nonexistent folders. localhost:81/fake_folder/ will still get me a 404 at localhost:81/fake_folder/.

**FOUND THE PROBLEM:**

I found my problem.

The problem folder contained a Wordpress site which kept trying to use the old address as stored in its database.

Comment: Google Chrome has some strange issues with `localhost` in general. Does it do this if you use another browser?

Comment: See this for details of this ongoing debarcle https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224215 and this for a more recent reemergence of the issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347513. Try using `http://127.0.0.1:81` to prove its the same issue

Comment: @RiggsFolly The same behavior is present when I use Firefox or Safari, and when I use 127.0.0.1 or my actual IP instead of localhost, and when I use a different computer.

Comment: Maybe you had better describe the EXACT changes you made to get Apache to use port 81. Maybe you missed something.